# How to detect memory type under Linux?

Tags: linux, hardware, memory

Which Linux utility can tell me if I have registered or unbuffered ECC memory in my server? `Lshw` and `dmidecode` do not work for me; `dmidecode` provides no information about registered vs. unbuffered:

```
Handle 0x0022, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0021
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM-1A
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could get this much info

Comment: Neither did I. I wanted to know if my RAM was ECC.. and came to know that it can be detected using "dmidecode"

Answer (score 12):

Data width = 64 (8 banks * 8 bits)

Total width = 72 (9 banks * 8 bits)

The extra bank indicates that ECC is active.

Comment: Nice (I hadn't noticed that), but the question was actually registered or unbuffered.

Answer (score 6):

Support for the “Registered” and “Unbuffered” type details (amongst others) was added in dmidecode 2.11 ([`dmidecode.c` revision 1.158](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/dmidecode/dmidecode.c?root=dmidecode&view=diff&r1=1.157&r2=1.158)). If you get the latest version, I expect it'll show either `Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)` or `Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)` (and probably `Type: DDR3` above).

Answer (score 1):

It's marked as `Type Detail: Synchronous`  So I'm going with Registered.  From [Newegg's wiki](http://www.newegg.com/product/CategoryIntelligenceArticle.aspx?articleId=126#topic3):

> Why is "unbuffered" the counterpart of "registered"? Buffers are known as "asynchronous" components, which is to say signals on the input pins appears directly on the out put pins. On the contrary, registers are known as "synchronous" components: new signals on the input pins do not show up immediately on the out put pins. Instead, they wait for the next tick of the system clock.